# Javascript code for collapsing HTML Blocks is not running

Tags: javascript, joomla

I tried to code some javascript to collapse specific HTML blocks. It is working when I try it in a HTML file on my local computer and the javascript code in a script block. But when I try to use it on my Joomla Website (the template allows me to insert my own javascript via a custom.js file), I can find the javascript code in the source code but it won't run. Does anybody have an idea?

This is the Code:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("oc-button");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    collaps = document.getElementsByClassName("oc-collaps");
    for (j = 0; j < collaps.length; j++) {
      if (collaps[j].style.display === "block") {
        collaps[j].style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    id = this.getAttribute("href");
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = document.getElementById(id);

    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the header part where the custom.js file is listed.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8byWE.png)

Comment: please show how you are inserting javascript in joomla view

Comment: I insert the javascript in a custom.js file and this is inserted in the header.

Comment: Have you checked the console if you have any error messages?

Comment: No, i dont. Thats the problem.

Comment: have you identified the problem?

Comment: No, i cant find the problem... It is still not running.

Comment: it also does not run when i insert the code via an extern javascript file on my local computer.

Comment: Show please how are you including the custom.js file